# Continuous and differentiable function $f(x)$ in $(x_1, x_2)$.

Tags: calculus, functions

Consider the continuous and differentiable function $f(x)$ in $[x_1, x_2]$.

Let $f'(x)$ be its derivative and

$f'(x_2) = 0$

Show that there exist a number $c >0$ and a $x_3 \in (x_1, x_2)$ such that $f'(x_3) = c(f(x_3)-f(x_1))$.

Apologies but I haven't touched calculus for more than 20 years. One of the few things I remember is that when the 1st derivative is zero, we have a local minimum or maximum.

(I am not a student or anything).

Comment: This does not sound right, what about $f(x) = (x-1)^2 + 1$ on the range $[0,1]$ -? Each slope on the interval is negative or 0, but the product $c(f(x_3) - f(x_1))$ is at least 0. So they are only equal when both are zero.. and that happens when $x_3 := x_2$ which then leads to the fact that $0 = c ( f(x_2) - f(x_1) ) $ which cannot be true as $c >0, f(x_2) - f(x_1) \neq 0 $ am I missing something?

Comment: Just made an edit: $x_3 \in (x_1, x_2)$

Comment: @CSch of x:  Why is $c(f(x_3)−f(x_1))$ at least zero? It seems to me the first term $c$ is required to be positive and the second is negative because $f$ is decreasing, so the product is negative, which is to say at *most* zero, right?

Comment: @WADon Yes but this function contradicts the statement (before the OP changed it from $[x_1, x_2]$ to $(x_1, x_2)$ )

Comment: @CSch, thanks - did not realise the question had changed!

Answer (score 0):

Edited to improve the middle step:

We can assume without loss of generality that $f(x_1) = 0$ (otherwise simply consider $f(x) -f(x_1)$).

Then, if $f(x)$ is identically zero, $x_3 \in (x_1,x_2)$ and $c>0$ may be chosen freely.

Otherwise, the function $\frac{1}{2} f(x)^2$ must be non-zero at some point $\xi $ in the interval $[x_1, x_2]$;  but $\xi > x_1$ because $f(x_1)=0$ and $f(\xi)^2$ is positive because $f(x)^2 \geqslant 0$.  Apply the mean value theorem to obtain $x_3 \in (x_1, \xi)$ satisfying,
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{1}{2}f(\xi)^2 - \frac{1}{2}f(x_1)^2}
{\xi-x_1} = f'(x_3)f(x_3)
\end{align}

The left side is strictly positive, so we have $x_3 \in (x_1,x_2)$ with
\begin{align}
f'(x_3)f(x_3) > 0 \tag{1}\label{e1}.
\end{align}
It follows neither $f(x_3)$ nor $f'(x_3)$ is zero and both have the same sign.  Accordingly we can define $c = f'(x_3)  / f(x_3) > 0 $ to obtain the required conclusion,
$$f'(x_3) = c f(x_3).$$

I note that this version does not require $f'(x_2)$ to be zero, so I wonder if the OP question ha been mis-transcribed.